# I have values in database still cannot retrieve them in window form

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am trying to retrieve values from tables in the database but can not do so.

Here is my code

```
int crs_Id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["crs_id"]);

SqlDataReader r1, r2, r3;

con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select Course_Title, Description from COURSE where course_ID='" + crs_Id + "'", con);
r1 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

Label5.Text = r1["Course_Title"].ToString();
Label6.Text = r1["Description"].ToString();

r1.Close();

SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("Select Tutor_ID from Teaching where  course_ID='" + crs_Id + "'", con);

r2 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

if (r2.Read())
{
    int tutor = Convert.ToInt32(r2["Tutor_ID"]);
    r2.Close();

    SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("Select Tutor_Name from TUTOR where  Tutor_Id='" + tutor + "'", con);

    r3 = cmd4.ExecuteReader();

    Label7.Text = "Tutor Name is " + r3["Tutor_Name"].ToString() + "";
    r3.Close();
}
else
    r2.Close();
```

I am getting the exception as shown in the screenshot

[image]

Comment: You're using dynamic query which is weak against SQL injection attack. You'd better to use parameterized query and stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because you're not reading the first row into the `SqlDataReader` returned from `ExecuteReader`. You can check `r1.HasRows` property and only access the columns if rows were returned. You also need to execute `r1.Read()` to get the first row.

```
r1 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
if ( r1.HasRows )
{
    r1.Read();
    Label5.Text = r1["Course_Title"].ToString();
    Label6.Text = r1["Description"].ToString();
}
else
{
    Label5.Text = "";
    Label6.Text = "";
}
```